# Why is the streaming fps is so large (about 600) when I do ffmpeg streaming a video file through udp?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

Ubuntu 12.04. ffmpeg version git-2013-03-26-1741fec Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers

The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg -i output_20140630.avi  -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.56:1234
```

The streaming fps is about 600, shown in the same terminal.

If I use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i output_20140630.avi  -f mpegts udp://236.0.0.1:200
```

Then it is fine. And I can use the command below to play the streamed video:

```
ffplay udp://236.0.0.1:2000
```

Comment: FFmpeg isn't going to control the output speed for you.  It is going to write data as fast as it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add -re, which means real time

```
ffmpeg -re -i output_20140630.avi  -f mpegts udp://236.0.0.1:200
```